# Integers and Rectangles

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Interesting problem of rectangles and integers is discussed on [Cut the Knot resource](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algebra/IntRectGraph.shtml)

> **Theorem**: Whenever a rectangle is tiled by rectangles each of which has at least one integer side, then the ambient rectangle has at least one integer side.

On cut the knot was provided the proof of Michael Paterson. The question is about the second observation of the proof.

> **Proof**:
>   ...We now make a second important observation:
>   The nodes of the graph associated with a tiling that correspond to the corners of the ambient rectangle have degree 1.
>   The degree of any other node is even: either 2 or 4.

Why actually the degree of any node is even : either 2 or 4? As I understood two vertices are connected by  the edge if two of them represent the vertical or horizontal borders of the tile. But if $n$ tiles are built in the column one of another, then the corresponding vertices will have degree $n$.

What I missed? Thank you in advance.

**Addendum:**

I realized that the problem is I don't fully understand how to build such a graph.

The following example, is the rectangle and a graph as I understood. Assume that all tiles have only $x$ component - integer (special).

Vertices of the graph are the corners of the tiles. Two vertices joined if the represent two different end of the same tile, so number of the edge in total equal number of the tiles (in assumption only x is special).

Where I am wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Each vertex is only connected to other vertices that are part of one of the tiles that meets at that vertex, and then only when the length of the side is special.  If you have $n$ tiles in a column, each vertex is only connected up one tile, down one tile, and maybe left and right one tile.  It can't be connect more than four directions.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the idea, I added simple example to my question, this is how I see it, could you please show the construction on the example, thank you.

Comment: @fog:  you shouldn't have the line between $1$ and $3$ as there is no segment connecting them.   The vertices at the top above $1$ and $3$ should be different vertices in your graph.  If the length is integral, those two should be connected in the graph.